# Why is a list variable sometimes not impacted by changes in function as I thought python3 works on pass by reference with list variables?

Tags: python-3.x, list, pass-by-reference, function-call, empty-list

For python3, I originally needed to extract odd and even positions from a list and assign it to new lists, then clear the original list. I thought lists were impacted by a function call through "pass by reference". Testing some scenarios, it works sometime. Could someone please explain how exactly python3 works here?

Case 1: empty list is populated with string as expected.

```
def func1(_in):
    _in.append('abc')

mylist = list()
print(f"Before:\nmylist = {mylist}")
func1(mylist)
print(f"After:\nmylist = {mylist}")
```

Output case 1:

```
Before:
mylist = []
After:
mylist = ['abc']
```

Case 2: middle list element is replaced with string as expected.

```
def func2(_in):
    _in[1] = 'abc'

mylist = list(range(3))
print(f"Before:\nmylist = {mylist}")
func2(mylist)
print(f"After:\nmylist = {mylist}")
```

Output case 2:

```
Before:
mylist = [0, 1, 2]
After:
mylist = [0, 'abc', 2]
```

Case 3: why is the list not empty after function call?

```
def func3(_in):
    _in = list()

mylist = list(range(3))
print(f"Before:\nmylist = {mylist}")
func3(mylist)
print(f"After:\nmylist = {mylist}")
```

Output case 3:

```
Before:
mylist = [0, 1, 2]
After:
mylist = [0, 1, 2]
```

Case 4: working exactly as expected, but note I have returned all three lists from function.

```
def func4_with_ret(_src, _dest1, _dest2):
    _dest1 = [val for val in _src[0:len(_src):2]]
    _dest2 = [val for val in _src[1:len(_src):2]]
    _src = list()
    return _src, _dest1, _dest2

source = list(range(6))
evens, odds = list(), list()
print(f"Before function call:\nsource = {source}\nevens = {evens}\nodds = {odds}")
source, evens, odds = func4_with_ret(source, evens, odds)
print(f"\nAfter function call:\nsource = {source}\nevens = {evens}\nodds = {odds}")
```

Output case 4:

```
Before function call:
source = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
evens = []
odds = []

After function call:
source = []
evens = [0, 2, 4]
odds = [1, 3, 5]
```

Case 5: why no impact on the variables outside the function if I do not explicitly return from function call?

```
def func5_no_ret(_src, _dest1, _dest2):
    _dest1 = [val for val in _src[0:len(_src):2]]
    _dest2 = [val for val in _src[1:len(_src):2]]
    _src = list()

source = list(range(6))
evens, odds = list(), list()
print(f"Before function call:\nsource = {source}\nevens = {evens}\nodds = {odds}")
func5_no_ret(source, evens, odds)
print(f"\nAfter function call:\nsource = {source}\nevens = {evens}\nodds = {odds}")
```

Output case 5:

```
Before function call:
source = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
evens = []
odds = []

After function call:
source = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
evens = []
odds = []
```

Thank you.

Comment: In short, you are asking how local and global variables are allocated. The main point is that when you do a new assignment, such as `_in = list()`, the `_in` will be local (only in the function), you create a new `_in` object. If you use `_in.clear()`, the change will be globally and result in an empty list. Similarly, `_dest1` is a new assignment (only local) and `_dest1.extend([val for val in _src[0:len(_src):2]])` is the global variant.

Comment: Yes and in case 1 and 2, you modify what is inside the list and this will propagate.

Comment: @Thymen: It's not really about local vs. global (those are scope terms that are misleading in this case; the `list` received into `_in` may not be a global, even if it is in the example code). `_in` itself is *always* local in this code, but sometimes it's aliasing a caller provided object (when function entered, this is always true), but it can be rebound to a different object (which may or may not be newly created; `_in = some_global` would alias it to the same object as a global, but `_in` remains local). The real issue is "mutation" vs. "rebinding"/"reassignment", not related to scope.

Comment: "I thought python3 works on pass by reference with list variables?" **No**. Python is *never* call by reference, nor call by value. Also, the evaluation strategy never depends on the type of the object. What you are seeing here is that your functions either mutate the list object, e.g. `_in.append` or `_in[i] = x` or they don't mutate the list object, `_in = list()`. That is merely *assignment*, and assignment never mutates. Check out: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ultimate problem is confusing (in-place) *mutation* with *rebinding* (also referred to somewhat less precisely as "reassignment").

In all the cases where the change isn't visible outside the function, you *rebound* the name inside the function. When you do:

```
name = val
```

it does not matter what used to be in `name`; it's *rebound* to `val`, and the reference to the old object is thrown away. When it's the last reference, this leads to the object being cleaned up; in your case, the argument *used* to alias an object also bound to a name in the caller, but after rebinding, that aliasing association is lost.

Aside for C/C++ folks: Rebinding is like assigning to a pointer variable, e.g. `int *px = pfoo;` (initial binding), followed later by `px = pbar;` (rebinding), where both `pfoo` and `pbar` are themselves pointers to `int`. When the `px = pbar;` assignment occurs, it doesn't matter that `px` used to point to the same thing as `pfoo`, it points to something new now, and following it up with `*px = 1;` (mutation, not rebinding) only affects whatever `pbar` points to, leaving the target of `pfoo` unchanged.

By contrast, *mutation* doesn't break aliasing associations, so:

```
name[1] = val
```

does rebind `name[1]` itself, but it doesn't rebind `name`; it continues to refer to the same object as before, it just mutates that object in place, leaving all aliasing intact (so all names aliasing the same object see the result of the change).

For your specific case, you could change the "broken" functions from rebinding to aliasing by changing to slice assignment/deletion or other forms of in-place mutation, e.g.:

```
def func3(_in):
    # _in = list()  BAD, rebinds
    _in.clear()     # Good, method mutates in place
    del _in[:]      # Good, equivalent to clear
    _in[:] = list() # Acceptable; needlessly creates empty list, but closest to original
                    # code, and has same effect

def func5_no_ret(_src, _dest1, _dest2):
    # BAD, all rebinding to new lists, not changing contents of original lists
    #_dest1 = [val for val in _src[0:len(_src):2]]
    #_dest2 = [val for val in _src[1:len(_src):2]]
    #_src = list()

    # Acceptable (you should just use multiple return values, not modify caller arguments)
    # this isn't C where multiple returns are a PITA
    _dest1[:] = _src[::2]  # Removed slice components where defaults equivalent
    _dest2[:] = _src[1::2] # and dropped pointless listcomp; if _src might not be a list
                           # list(_src[::2]) is still better than no-op listcomp
    _src.clear()

    # Best (though clearing _src is still weird)
    retval = _src[::2], _src[1::2]
    _src.clear()
    return retval

    # Perhaps overly clever to avoid named temporary:
    try:
        return _src[::2], _src[1::2]
    finally:
        _src.clear()
```

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer. Learned a lot from your examples!

Comment: @rbewoor: Glad I could help. If your question is fully answered, would you please click the check box under the voting arrows to accept the answer? No hurry (if someone else provides a better answer, please give the check to them), but it's a good way to indicate that your problem is fully resolved.

Comment: Done sir! Thanks for telling me about the check mark.