# A list used as an Argument is being changed despite not returning the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def main():

startingBoard = [
    [5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
    [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
    [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
    [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
    [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
    [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
    [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
    [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
    [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]
]

printBoard(startingBoard)
print("^^ This is the startingBoard")

index = solveRow(startingBoard, 0)

printBoard(startingBoard)
print("^^ This should still be the startingBoard but has changed despite no return list")

if index < 10:
    solveColumn(startingBoard, index)

printBoard(startingBoard)
print("^^ This should also print startingBoard but shows the changes of both functions")



def solveRow(board, row):

for index, num in enumerate(board[row]):
    column = []
    for r in board:
        column.append(r[index])
    for i in range(9):
        if num == 0:
            if i+1 not in board[row] and i+1 not in column:
                board[row][index] = i+1


if 0 in board[row]:
    index = board[row].index(0)
    return index
return 10

def solveColumn(board, colIndex):
column = []
for r in board:
    column.append(r[colIndex])

for rowNum, row in enumerate(board):
    for index, num in enumerate(column):
            for i in range(9):
                if num == 0:
                    if i+1 not in column and i+1 not in board[rowNum]:
                        column[index] = i+1

for i, row in enumerate(board):
    row[colIndex] = column[i]

return board

def printBoard(board):
print("       ---SUDOKU BOARD--- ")
print()
print("    " + "1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9")
print("   ---------------------------")
for i in range(9):
    print(" " + str(i+1) + " " + str(board[i]) + " " + str(i+1))
print("   ---------------------------")
print("    " + "1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9")
print()
print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

And this is outputing:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   ---------------------------
 1 [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0] 1
 2 [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0] 2
 3 [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0] 3
 4 [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3] 4
 5 [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1] 5
 6 [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6] 6
 7 [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0] 7
 8 [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5] 8
 9 [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9] 9
   ---------------------------
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

^^ This is the startingBoard

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   ---------------------------
 1 [5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 2, 0] 1
 2 [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0] 2
 3 [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0] 3
 4 [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3] 4
 5 [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1] 5
 6 [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6] 6
 7 [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0] 7
 8 [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5] 8
 9 [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9] 9
   ---------------------------
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

^^ This should still be the startingBoard but has changed despite no return list

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   ---------------------------
 1 [5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 2, 8] 1
 2 [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 7] 2
 3 [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4] 3
 4 [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3] 4
 5 [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1] 5
 6 [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6] 6
 7 [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 2] 7
 8 [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5] 8
 9 [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9] 9
   ---------------------------
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

^^ This should also print startingBoard but shows the changes of both functions

Essentially I'm using a list as an argument to a function, but if something happens in the logic of that function I'd like to use the original list in another function. The problem is the list gets changed through each function despite not returning the argument list.

I imagine it's a dumb mistake. Possibly global variable or making the original a tuple, that can then be transferred to a working list for checking. Just looking for help. Thanks.

I'm new to python and thought I'd take a stab at a Sudoku solver. Please don't offer assistance on the logic as I'd like to solve this on my own, then compare with a more efficient approach to improve my Python. Sorry for the messy code as I'm learning and usually clean it up after solving everything. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Lists are passed by reference. If you don't want to modify the original, make a deep copy

Comment: so if I made a workingBoard that had the same value as the original list, then passed that into the function. that should work? and just update the workingBoard list to the original list when needed?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65956937/why-is-a-list-variable-sometimes-not-impacted-by-changes-in-function-as-i-though?noredirect=1#comment116617209_65956937) question, or [this](https://discuss.python.org/t/why-do-my-lists-get-modified-when-passed-to-a-function/5036) discussion. Also please restore the indentation of your code question, it is very hard for us to know what you  want to return. Short summary `board[row][index] = i+1`, is mutating the list, use `new_board = board[:]` or `from copy import deepcopy` `new_board = deepcopy(board)` to prevent it.

Comment: Basically you need to do: `board = solve(board.copy())` - but since board is 2D you'll need to do `deepcopy` instead

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are by default passed by references in Python.

So, in the `solveRow` when you change `board`, you are effectively changing the same board object you passed.

```
def solveRow(board, row):

  for index, num in enumerate(board[row]):
    column = []
    for r in board:
        column.append(r[index])
    for i in range(9):
        if num == 0:
            if i+1 not in board[row] and i+1 not in column:
                board[row][index] = i+1
```

You can look at the `copy()` and `deepcopy()` methods that creates a copy of the list object to avoid unwanted overrides on the original object.

Comment: Ok this makes sense now. I should essentially create a workingBoard list that'll get changed in the function, but updated back to the original when necessary.